# Using %02x vs \x in C

Tags: c, hex

I am sending command hex codes to a motor controller, and when I use the following the motor will work as expected, but it isn't using the speed variable but just a hard coded speed of 0.

```
snprintf (command, 8, "\x88\x00"); //88 is direction and 00 is speed
```

Now logically I try

```
snprintf (command, 8, "\x88\x%02x", speed); //where speed is an int
```

With this I get the error using \x with no following hex values.

I then try just using the regular %02x and %x for speed

```
snprintf (command, 8, "\x88%02x", speed);
```

With this I printed out command and I get a buffer symbol for \x88 looks like a "?", and a 00 follows that. So something like..

```
?00
```

How can I write the full hex buffer with speed and direction into the command buffer to write to the controller?

I would appreciate the help

Thank you

Comment: you are confusing format string syntax with string literal escape sequence syntax. `\xDD` will put the character with code `DD` into the string literal itself. It has nothing to do with string formatting using `printf()` and co. Meanwhile, `%02x` is a conversion specifier for `[sn]printf()`, which converts the given integer to its hexadecimal representation and puts it in the buffer.

Comment: So then the question should be how do I take the speed integer and place it in the command buffer as snprintf (command, 8, "\x88\x00") does?

Comment: `snprintf(command, 8, "\x88\x00")` always produces the very same output. It will put two bytes, with numerical value 0x88 and 0x00, into the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%02x formats an int argument, \x02 inserts a literal byte 0x02 into the string

Edit: to send binary commands to the controller, either use the \x02 syntax to embed
the command into the output string, or use the %s conversion to embed binary command strings
into the output string.  You can say

```
char *cmd_turn_on = "\x01\x02";
sprintf(cmdbuf, "controller, do: %s", cmd_turn_on);
```

you can use %c to embed numbers as bytes into the string

```
char *cmd_fmt = "%c%c";
sprintf(cmdbuf, cmd_fmt, 0x88, 0x02);
```

will place into cmdbuf the two bytes "\x88\x02"

Comment: You still have not converted the speed integer into the raw hex and placed it in cmd_turn_on buffer, you have also just hard coded the speed to x02.